# Change speed of R ggplot gganimate when using rmarkdown render

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown, gganimate

I have some `ggplot` objects animated via `gganimate`, and I would like to change the speed of the animation.

Here is a reproducible example from the github repo here: https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate

```
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, frame = year)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_log10()

library(gganimate)
gganimate(p)
```

This animation takes about 12 seconds to cycle all the way through.  How could I make it cycle through in say 6 seconds?

I have tried setting `time` to different values, but to no avail, and it is not clear from the help page.

```
gganimate(p, time = 0.1)
```

## Update

The `interval` seems to generally work, but still unclear to me how I could make this work within an Rmarkdown report.  As an example, if I place the code below in a file called `test.R` and then run `rmarkdown::render('test.R')` my animation runs at the default speed instead of the expected increased speed.  How would I make this work in the context of `rmarkdown::render`?  I've been trying various things from looking here: https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate/commit/3aa2064cdfff30feb2b00724ad757fd5a5a62621, but to no avail.

```
knitr::opts_chunk$set(message = FALSE, warning = FALSE, fig.show = 'animate')

library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
theme_set(theme_bw())

p <- ggplot(gapminder, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, size = pop, color = continent, frame = year)) +
    geom_point() +
    scale_x_log10()

library(gganimate)
capture.output(gganimate(p, interval = 0.2))
```

Comment: Per the end of [the README](https://github.com/dgrtwo/gganimate), you need to set the `interval` chunk option, e.g. `{r my-animation, interval = 1/60}`

Answer (score 2):

We need to set `interval` option:

```
gganimate(p, interval = 0.2)
```

From [animation package](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=animation) manual, see `ani.options`:

> **interval** a positive number to set the time interval of the animation (unit in seconds); default to be 1.

Comment: thanks, any idea of how this works when using `rmarkdown::render`?  See updated question for details, thank you!

Comment: @jmuhlenkamp I would suggest to ask this as a new question.